# How do I know that Keras is optimising the correct values in my custom loss function?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, opticalflow

```
def charbonnier(I_x, I_y, I_t, U, V, e):
    loss = K.sqrt(K.pow((U*I_x + V*I_y + I_t), 2) + e)
    return K.sum(loss)
```

I am training an unsupervised model with the differentiable loss function shown below (and above in code). `I_x`, `I_y` and `I_t` are constants, and the goal is to learn the U and V which minimises E(F).

[image: loss]

My question is, how can I be sure that Keras is optimising the correct weights U and V? Is there some sort of way to ensure that the constants are frozen and that only U and V are optimisable?

If it is any help, the output of my model is a (1, 240, 320, 2) tensor, where the channels are U and V. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: solve the problem by hand and see if keras returns the same value

Comment: And if it doesn't, how do I ensure that it does?

Comment: if it doesn't then you need to either double check your hand calculation or your algorithm